# Anyone knows why `atd` is `masked` in Ubuntu 21.10? Is it a bug or a feature?

Tags: server, updates, systemd

I have recently upgraded from Ubuntu Server 20.04.3 to 21.10 and have just noticed `atd` process is marked as `masked`.

Is that intended or should it be unmasked?

```
$ systemctl status atd
○ atd.service
     Loaded: masked (Reason: Unit atd.service is masked.)
     Active: inactive (dead)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `at` package moved from -main to -universe after 20.04. It's no longer part of a stock Ubuntu install.

Services may be masked if the corresponding application is not installed.

So check that you have the package installed: `apt list at`